# how to work with 2 notifications in Android?

Tags: android, notifications

I have 2 `StatusBar Notification` in my app. These notifications appear in the same time in app, and I can see only the last notification. And, if I press the `Button Clear`, both of them are cleared. How to work with more than one notification in android? 
The second question is how to display the text of `notification` on **multiple rows**. I can see only the beginning of the text.

Here is my code :

for the first notification :

```
private void setNotifiy() {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence NotificationTicket = "You have a notification";

    CharSequence contentTitle = "You are close to " + name_shop + "!!!";
    CharSequence contentText = "So,you can go for shopping:)";

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            NotificationTicket, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ShopsOnMap.class);
    System.out.println("DDDDd" + lat_choose + "!!!");
    notificationIntent.putExtra("latshop", lat_choose);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("longshop", long_choose);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
            contentIntent);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
}
```

and for second notification :

```
private void hey(String list) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence NotificationTicket = "Hey";

    CharSequence contentTitle = "Shopping!!";
    CharSequence contentText = "Today,you must go for shopping for your list ' "
            + list + "'" + "Don't forget!!!";

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
            NotificationTicket, when);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, Lists.class);

    PendingIntent intent =
      PendingIntent.getActivity(Lists.this, 0,
       notifyIntent, android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, intent);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your codes are using the same ID for both notifications.

As you might know, the answer is already on this documentation:
[Creating Status Bar Notifications.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

You may focus on two things covered on the documentation:

1. **Notification ID**. This is useful for creating a different notifications.
2. "**Creating a Custom Extended View**" section to create notification in multiple rows.